# Catch block running before Try block in signup process

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, async-await, try-catch

I'm experiencing an issue where the catch block in my signup process is running before the try block. When I attempt to sign up, the catch block displays the error message before the success message is shown. This behavior is unexpected, as I would expect the try block to execute first.

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
const onSignup = async (values: any) => {
        try {
          setLoading(true);
          const response = await axios.post(`/api/users/signup`, values);
          const responseData = response.data;
          if (!responseData.error) {
            toast.success("Signup success", successState);
            router.push("/login");
          } else {
            if (responseData.error === "User already exists") {
              toast.error("User already exists", errorState);
            }
          }
        } catch (error: any) {
          toast.error(
            "An error occurred during sign in. Please try again later.",
            errorState
          );
        } finally {
          setLoading(false);
        }
      };
```

Comment: `catch` never runs before `try`. Possibly explanations for what you see include that `onSignup` is called multiple times or that your toaster displays messages in the wrong order. So do some debugging what the `values` passed to each call are, and what `error` is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

In dev mode, this may be happening due to multiple renders - Check out this thread - [Why my nextjs component is rendering twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71847778/9640177)

So, actually, your catch block is not called twice. The error you see is from the previous render.